# Changing form elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking to have a form drop-down list that lists all Brands for a specific type of item. After selecting a Brand from that list, a new drop-down list will appear with a list of all the different Models for the selected Brand.

How do I make a specific drop-down list appear depending on what Brand was selected using JavaScript.
The code in my JSFiddle link is extremely bare, I just made it to give somewhat of a visual.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TobaccoJoe/PjFMh/1/)

```
<select>
    <option>Select Make
    <option>Toyota 
    <option>Honda
    <option>Ford
</select>
```

Comment: You need to know how to modify the DOM (maybe read about it), and how to add elements to the DOM (you will be removing and adding elements to your select).

Comment: So I tried to build up on this by adding a Size drop-down list that comes after the selected Model. I got close to doing it, but something is wrong. I don't fully understand the code in the for loop, but I think that the problem lies there. Regardless of what Make you choose, it only shows the 1st three items in the modelArr array.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TobaccoJoe/Svnx7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#SelectBox').change(function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        $( "#Example").empty();
        $( "#Example").append('<option>Corolla<option><option>Camry<option><option>Prius<option>');
    }
    else if (this.selectedIndex == 2)
    {
        $( "#Example").empty();
        $( "#Example").append('<option>Accord<option><option>Civic<option><option>Odyssey<option>');
    }
    else if (this.selectedIndex == 3)
    {
        $( "#Example").empty();
        $( "#Example").append('<option>Focus<option><option>Explorer<option><option>Taurus<option>');
    }

});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">

Make:<br />
<select id="SelectBox">
    <option>Select Make</option>
    <option id='Toyota' onclick='showMe()' >Toyota</option>
    <option id='Honda'>Honda</option>
    <option id='Ford'>Ford</option>
</select><br />

Model:<br />
<select id="Example">
    <option>example
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach: http://jsfiddle.net/PjFMh/2/

To update the content, you need a listener for the changes that will happen to the make selector. First, you need to grab a hold of the selector itself (`var $make = document.getElementById('make')`) to which you can set the listener. This is done by `$make.onchange = function() { ... }`. Inside this function, grab the index of the currently selected index so you can determine which array of models you want to display.

First, clear the content of the model selector, so you are ready to fill it with new content. For each model, create a new `<option>` and fill it with the current model. Then, append this to the selector itself.

There's different approaches to where to store the data (for make and model), but I choose to store it as arrays in JavaScript. You could have had HTML elements that you could hide/show with the code, but I think this is more modular if you were to change something later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix you HTML, `<option>` must have a closing tag.

One of many approaches is http://jsfiddle.net/Tt5gf/1/, I wrote you some comments, try to play with it - add or remove some options, change existing one, have some practice

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach is to have all the second options in text files and to load them as a click or change event on the first selector.  Like this:

```
$("#firstSelector").click(function() {
  x = this.value;
   $("#secondSelector").load("[path to text file]/' + x + '.txt");
});
```

So, you give each text file the name of the value of each option in the first selector and the content of each text file is the html for the options to be loaded in the second selector.  To add/change options in the second selector, just replace the appropriate text files.

Comment: Wow, those were quick responses.
I've studied enough into JS DOM and Jquery to know what you guys are saying.
You've helped me out alot. Thanks guys! :)